# slurmdbd service can't connect to MySQL at startup, but succeeds manually

Tags: mysql, services, init.d

I installed `slurm-llnl` and `slurm-llnl-slurmdbd` on a Ubuntu 14.04 workstation. I successfully configured SLURM, but am having trouble with the `slurmdbd` service and the mySQL database

After a system boot, `service --status-all` shows

```
 [ + ] slurm-llnl
 [ - ] slurm-llnl-slurmdbd
```

and `/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.log`

```
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.179] debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/auth_munge.so
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.222] auth plugin for Munge (http://code.google.com/p/munge/) loaded
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.223] debug3: Success.
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.223] debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/accounting_storage_mysql.so
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.581] debug2: mysql_connect() called for db slurm_acct_db
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.643] error: mysql_real_connect failed: 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[2015-11-03T14:52:30.643] fatal: The database must be up when starting the MYSQL plugin.
```

If I now start the service manually with

```
$ sudo service slurm-llnl-slurmdbd start
```

everything seems to work fine:

```
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.324] debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/auth_munge.so
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.324] auth plugin for Munge (http://code.google.com/p/munge/) loaded
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.324] debug3: Success.
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.324] debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/accounting_storage_mysql.so
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.326] debug2: mysql_connect() called for db slurm_acct_db
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.367] debug4: (accounting_storage_mysql.c:1069) query
show tables like 'user_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.367] debug4: (accounting_storage_mysql.c:1089) query
show tables like 'localhost_assoc_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.367] debug4: (accounting_storage_mysql.c:1106) query
show columns from "localhost_assoc_table" where Field='is_def';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.392] debug4: (accounting_storage_mysql.c:1069) query
show tables like 'user_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.392] debug4: (accounting_storage_mysql.c:1089) query
show tables like 'qtech_assoc_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.392] debug4: (accounting_storage_mysql.c:1106) query
show columns from "qtech_assoc_table" where Field='is_def';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.412] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:788) query
show tables like 'assoc_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.412] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:829) query
show tables like 'cluster_event_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.412] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:852) query
show tables like 'job_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.412] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:876) query
show tables like 'last_ran_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.412] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:897) query
show tables like 'resv_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.413] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:920) query
show tables like 'step_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.413] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:942) query
show tables like 'suspend_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.413] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:964) query
show tables like 'cluster_hour_usage_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.413] debug4: (as_mysql_convert.c:1004) query
show tables like 'wckey_table';
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.449] Accounting storage MYSQL plugin loaded
[2015-11-03T14:54:08.449] debug3: Success.
...
```

I'm not an expert Ubuntu user, but it seems to me that the mySQL service is not ready when `slurm-llnl-slurmdbd` is started. However, it is correctly listed in the dependencies. Here is the beginning of `/etc/init.d/slurm-llnl-slurmdbd`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 345 90 10
# description: SLURMDBD is a database server interface for \
#              SLURM (Simple Linux Utility for Resource Management).
#
# processname: /usr/sbin/slurmdbd
# pidfile: /var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.pid
#
# config: /etc/sysconfig/slurm
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          slurm-llnl-slurmdbd
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network munge
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network munge
# Should-Start:      $named mysql
# Should-Stop:       $named mysql
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: SLURM database daemon
# Description:       Start slurm to provide database server for SLURM
### END INIT INFO

SBINDIR=/usr/sbin
LIBDIR=/usr/lib
CONFFILE="/etc/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.conf"
DESCRIPTION="slurm-llnl database server interface"
NAME="slurmdbd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems and found out that mysql is controlled by initctl and not the by the old system V init.

Are you sure that the mysqld is running? Check it with "initctl status mysql".

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, MySQL is started with an Upstart unit, but SLURM is still started by a SysV-init script, which are all started by the "rc" Upstart unit. Initially, there is no dependencies between these two, so they can be started in parallel.

It seems to work reliably in my setup after I modified the MySQL unit to start before the rc unit, and not just on a run-level, i.e. replace the line "start on runlevel [2345]" in /etc/init/mysql.conf with "start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]".

Use these two lines if you want it automated, for instance in a preseed script:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local -add /etc/init/mysql.conf
sudo sed -i "s/^\(start on\) runlevel \[2345\]/\1 starting rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]/" /etc/init/mysql.conf
```